# JavascriptExecutor (Selenium WebDriver C#) keeps returning null objects

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to retrieve HTML elements via jQuery and I keep getting null reference point exception, in every JavascriptExecutor statement I write. Is it me?

Here's my code:

```
List<Object> list= (List<Object>)(IJavaScriptExecutor)Browser).ExecuteScript("$('tbody').find('tr')");
 list.Count.ShouldBeLessThan(rowsWithNewActivity);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not returning anything from your JavaScript execution. Try this:

```
List<object> list = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)Browser).ExecuteScript("return $('tbody').find('tr');") as List<object>;
```

This should no longer return a null value, but rather should return the list you're looking for.